# Error While updating ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

[image]

I tried run sudo apt-get install -f and received the following message:

```
setting up chkrootkit (0.53-1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package chkrootkit (--configure):
 installed chkrootkit package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bsd-mailx:
 bsd-mailx depends on default-mta | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package default-mta is not installed.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package bsd-mailx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up rkhunter (1.4.6-8) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package rkhunter (--configure):
 installed rkhunter package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chkrootkit
 bsd-mailx
 rkhunter
```

Comment: Regarding the last set of errors, it appears you have 2 process trying to install programs.

Comment: The command `lslocks` can be useful to find the competiting process.